# How to add duplicates in array in one row

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [0] => 1
        [1] => Name1
        [2] => Ingridient1
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [0] => 2
        [1] => Name2
        [2] => Ingridient1
    )
    [2] => Array(
        [0] => 2
        [1] => Name2
        [2] => Ingridient2
    )
)
```

How can I add in one key the duplicates like Name2 to have Ingridient1 and Ingridient2...IngridientN?

Comment: how should be defined the limit of number of ingredients? can you show the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$my_arr = array(array(1, 'Name1', 'Ingredient1'), array(2, 'Name2', 'Ingredient1'), array(2, 'Name2', 'Ingredient2') );


$my_final_array = array();

foreach($my_arr as $val){
    if (!isset($my_final_array[$val[1]])){
        $my_final_array[$val[1]] = array();
    }

    if (!in_array($val[2], $my_final_array[$val[1]])){
        $my_final_array[$val[1]][] = $val[2];
    }    
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($my_final_array);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Name1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ingredient1
        )

    [Name2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ingredient1
            [1] => Ingredient2
        )

)
```

How to echo:

```
echo '<pre>';
foreach($my_final_array as $name => $ingredients){
    echo $name . ' - Ingredients: ' . implode(', ', $ingredients).PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Echo output:

```
Name1 - Ingredients: Ingredient1
Name2 - Ingredients: Ingredient1, Ingredient2
```

Comment: How can i get the [Name] now?

Comment: `foreach($my_final_array as $name => $ingredients)` will give you `$name` and an array of unique `$ingredients`

Comment: Ye but i want to echo them like Name2 - Ingridients: Ingredient1, Ingredient2

Comment: Amazing.Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

A small change to the @mani answer

```
$array = array(array(1, 'Name1', 'Ingredient1'), array(2, 'Name2', 'Ingredient1'), array(2, 'Name2', 'Ingredient2') );


$final_array = array();

foreach($array as $val){
     $final_array[$val[1]][] = $val[2]; 
}
```

Comment: interesting, i would have thought it would throw warnings. Also, it should be `$final_array[$val[1]][] = $val[2];`. But i think it will still add duplicated i.e. if `Integredient1` would be added twice without checking for uniqueness.